# Change the size of plot panel in lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem with a `lattice` graphic in R. I build a double y axis plot with `lattice`. It works awesome. I add the code and `dput` version of my data (`xx` list of data frames in the final part):

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
#First graph
#Format
comma_fomatter <- function (lim, logsc = FALSE, at = NULL, ...) 
{
  ans <- yscale.components.default(lim = lim, logsc = logsc, 
                                   at = at, ...)
  xx = as.numeric(ans$left$labels$labels)
  ans$left$labels$labels <- formatC(xx, format="fg",big.mark = ",")
  ans
}
#Plot
DD=barchart(a1 ~ a5,xx, yscale.components =comma_fomatter)
#Second graph
#Format
percent1 <- function(x, digits = 2, format = "f", ...)
{
  paste(formatC(100 * x, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%", sep = "")
}
percent <- function (lim, logsc = FALSE, at = NULL, ...) 
{
  ans <- yscale.components.default(lim = lim, logsc = logsc, 
                                   at = at, ...)
  xx = as.numeric(ans$left$labels$labels)
  ans$left$labels$labels <- percent1(xx)
  ans
}
#Second plot
D3=xyplot(a3+a4 ~ a5, xx, type = "b",yscale.components=percent)
#Final graph
DF=doubleYScale(DD, D3,style1 = 3, style2 = 0, add.ylab2 = FALSE,text = c("a3", "a4","a1"),main="Nuevo Gráfico")
```

All works perfect but when I plot `DF` I got this:
[image]

How you can see the left side y axis doesn't show its values and I think this fact is due to the size of square that has all plots. My question is if it is any way to reduce the size of that square and showing the complete values inside of y axis scale. The `dput()` version of my list of data frames is the next:

```
xx=structure(list(a1 = c(560492.29, 1433973.37, 3016748.66, 4241217.73, 
6251742.27, 6757161.24, 7408081.05, 7899980.33), a2 = 1:8, a3 = c(0, 
0.00793734405263048, 0.0129172080248807, 0.0324335034787285, 
0.0397094648625047, 0.0555107413716237, 0.0521541081141384, 0.0515512600016815
), a4 = c(0.0142731668976214, 0.010460445301017, 0.0928151568317925, 
0.0707344020275045, 0.0303915279604129, 0.0517968992552855, 0.0202481585970229, 
0.0253165187311296), a5 = structure(1:8, .Label = c("abr 2013", 
"may 2013", "jun 2013", "jul 2013", "ago 2013", "sep 2013", "oct 2013", 
"nov 2013"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3", 
"a4", "a5"))
```

I have looked for any advice at lattice graphics book but I can't solve this element. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it didn't work for you. I've taken the liberty to reformat your code, other than that nothing important has changed. Anyway, here's the plot:

[image]

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be related to the settings of lattice (see `?trellis.par.get`). I've updated the source accordingly, that should solve the problem.

And here's the source:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

# xx <- ... paste your dataset here

# Adapt these to your needs:
parSettings <- list(layout.widths=list(left.padding=5))

#First graph
comma_formatter <- function (lim, logsc = FALSE, at = NULL, ...)  {
  ans <- yscale.components.default(lim = lim, logsc = logsc, at = at, ...)
  xxPrime <- as.numeric(ans$left$labels$labels)
  ans$left$labels$labels <- formatC(xxPrime, format = "fg", big.mark = ",")
  ans
}
#Plot
DD <- barchart(a1 ~ a5, xx, yscale.components = comma_formatter, par.settings = parSettings)

#Second graph
percent <- function (lim, logsc = FALSE, at = NULL, ...) {
  # Helper function (never needed elsewhere, so we can declare it here)
  percent1 <- function(x, digits = 2, format = "f", ...)
    paste(formatC(100 * x, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%", sep = "")

  ans <- yscale.components.default(lim = lim, logsc = logsc, at = at, ...)
  xxPrime <- as.numeric(ans$left$labels$labels)
  ans$left$labels$labels <- percent1(xxPrime)
  ans
}
#Plot
D3 <- xyplot(a3+a4 ~ a5, xx, type = "b", yscale.components = percent, par.settings = parSettings)

#Final graph
DF <- doubleYScale(DD, D3, style1 = 3, style2 = 0, add.ylab2 = FALSE,
                   text = c("a3", "a4", "a1"), main = "Nuevo Gráfico")
plot(DF)
```

Comment: Thanks @fotNelton but I am getting the same problem maybe do you know what is your window configuration, I am working with RStudio and R 2.15 in windows 7 and I got this problem maybe some advice about this

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I've used RStudio and R 3.0.2 on OS X, but I don't think that the OS matters. Maybe it helps if you start with a fresh workspace and enter only the above (including your dataset)? That's what I would try.

Comment: I tried this and give me the same result maybe any par.setting problems for me @fotNelton

Comment: As a matter of fact, I currently have no idea what might be the culprit in your case. Nevertheless I have edited the source code given above after I realized that you're using `xx` both as dataset and as temporary variable within functions. This is no problem at all but I wanted to make sure that there's no accidental name collision. Admittedly, I don't think that this will solve your problem, but it's maybe still worth giving it a shot.

Comment: One more thing: Have you tried updating RStudio, R (current version is 3.0.3) and in particular also the R-packages which are already installed on your system? You can do that by typing `update.packages(checkBuilt=T, ask=F)`. Note that when you're using a custom directory for the packages, you have to provide `lib.loc` when calling `update.packages`.

Comment: Please check if the updated source works for you. I have added a variable `parSettings` which is used whenever one of lattice's plotting functions is called throughout the source. These settings modify the margin of the plot, thus allowing for more space for the labels on the left-hand side. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Awesome man @fotNelton that works perfect, only aditional question I have set to put a main in the graph but I can't get this, also I would like to put legeng at the bottom maybe some advice about this. Thanks

Comment: @Duck Great that it finally worked out. As far as the main title and the legend are concerned, I'd have to google it myself, I'm really sorry mate. Cheers!

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot of crack in graphics I will google that elements @fotNelton